# If str is a "string slice", why don't std::slice blanket implementations work on str?

Tags: string, rust, slice

In the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) and [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), `str` is being referred to as a slice (in the book they say a slice into a `String`).
So, I would expect `str` to behave the same as any other slice: I should be able to for example use blanket implementations from `std::slice`.
However, this does not seem to be the case:

While this works as expected ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d3070df700ea28ec55fdd6480b4f734a)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let int_slice = &vec[..];
    for chunk in int_slice.chunks(2) {
        println!("{:?}", chunk);
    }
}
```

This fails to compile: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b85848a3b08b665c1e637aab9977a179))

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello world";
    for chunk in s.chunks(3) {
        println!("{}", chunk);
    }
}
```

With the following error message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `chunks` found for type `&str` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     for chunk in s.chunks(3) {
  |                    ^^^^^^
```

Does this mean `str` is not a regular slice?

If it's not: What is the characteristic of `str`, which make it impossible to be a slice?

On a side-note: If the above is an "int slice", shouldn't `str` be described as a "char slice"?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of `str` starts with

> The `str` type, also called a 'string slice',

The quotes are important here. A `str` is a 'string slice', which is not the same as a simple 'slice'. They share the name because they are very similar, but are not related to each other otherwise.

You can however get a regular slice out of a 'str' using [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes). There is also a [mutable version](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes_mut), which is unsafe because you could use it to break an important invariant of `&str` over `&[u8]`: UTF-8 validity.

Comment: I am just trying to learn here: Is there an inherent quality to str, which make it impossible to be a `&[u8]` or `&[char]`?

Comment: @Jan15: yes. A `&str` is always UTF-8 valid, while a `&[u8]` can contain anything. `u8` is also not a really useful type to use with strings most of the time (neither is `char`, which is why `&str` is also different from `&[char]`).